# How to specify particular setter for property of a class?

Tags: kotlin

I'm following a course in kotlin and they speak about how to make a special setter but I don't know how to make it working here is my code :

```
class Course (val id:Int, title:String, var duree:Int, var state:Boolean){
var title:String = title
    get(){return field}
    set(value){field = "my awesome" + value}
 }
 
 fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var myCourse:Course = Course (0, "stuff", 50, true)
    println(myCourse.title)
 }
```

but it keep output 'stuff' instead of 'my awesome stuff'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myCourse:Course = Course(0, "stuff", 50, true)
```

With the above line of code, the `Course` object is initialized with the constructor. Here **the setter is not called**, hence it prints `stuff` and not `my awesome stuff`. The setter would get called only if you use

```
myCourse.title = "stuff"
```

If you want the setter to be called on initialization, you need to set the value of `title` in an `init` block as below

```
class Course(val id: Int, title: String, var duree: Int, var state: Boolean) {

    var title: String = title
        set(value) {
            field = "my awesome $value"
        }

    init {
        this.title = title
    }
}
```

Or, you can drop the custom setter and set the value of `title` with your custom value in the `init` block itself

```
class Course(val id: Int, var title: String, var duree: Int, var state: Boolean) {

    init {
        this.title = "my awesome ${this.title}"
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't knew that specific setter wasn't used unless called by init, it's not very intuitive but good to know

Answer (score 1):

The custom setter is only used when you explicitly set the value. The custom setter is not used when you initialize the backing field at the declaration site using `= title`.

If you want the custom setter to be applied using the initial value, you can add an `init` block to your class:

```
    init {
        this.title = title
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get you example working applying a little change in your code:

```kotlin
class Course (val id:Int, __title:String, var duree:Int, var state:Boolean){
    var title:String = ""
        get() { return field}
        set(value){field = "my awesome" + value}
        
    init {
        title = __title
    }
 }
```

The difference seems to be the explicit assignment `title = __title`, that forces the usage of the custom setter...